# Using conditionals in a Playbook to execute based on IP address

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts

I have to change the windows computer name on 40 machines in AWS. I tried using the gather_facts to set a condition to only execute if the ip matches. But for some reason it doesn't pick it up. My solution so far to the problem(highly inefficient is to make individual host groups one per ip. I know there has to be a better way to go about this any input would be appreciated.

This is what I have that works

```
---
- hosts: windows_machine1
  gather_facts: yes

  tasks:



    - name: Change the hostname to newname1
      win_hostname:
        name: newname1
      register: res

- hosts: windows_machine2
  tasks:

    - name: Change the hostname to newname2
      win_hostname:
        name: newname2
      register: res

    - name: Reboot
      win_reboot:
      when: res.reboot_required
```

I tried two ways to make the conditional both resulted in a error when ran.

```
---
- hosts: windows_machine1
  gather_facts: yes

  tasks:



    - name: Change the hostname to newname1
      win_hostname:
        name: newname1
      register: res
      when: ansible_facts['ansible_all_ipv4_addresses'] == '10.x.x.x


    - name: Change the hostname to newname2
      win_hostname:
        name: newname2
      register: res
      when: ansible_facts['address'] == '10.x.x.x'

    - name: Reboot
      win_reboot:
      when: res.reboot_required
```

It will fail saying the conditional check failed. Because my conditionals are bad. Does anyone know how to make a conditional based on ip?

Comment: Can't you use a list with objects as the list entries, e.g. like this: `host_mapping: - { old: 127.0.0.1, new: newName1}` and so on?

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I only run Ansible on Linux hosts, so I guess there is a chance things are different on Windows hosts.

You don't specify `ansible_facts`, and instead just start at the specific root fact.

In the first case, the fact you are trying to get to is not going to help you, because it returns a list of all the IP's on the system. Even if there is only one, it still returns a list, which you can't then simply make a string comparison against.

This should do what you want in the first instance:

```
- name: Change the hostname to newname2
  win_hostname:
    name: newname2
  register: res
  when: "ansible_default_ipv4.address == '10.0.0.1'"
```

Are you intending to duplicate this block of code, one per host? If so consider setting a variable to lookup IP and new name:

```
- hosts: all
  vars:
    ip_newname:
      10.0.0.1: newname1
      10.0.0.2: newname2
      10.0.0.3: newname3
  tasks:
    - name: Change the hostname
      win_hostname:
        name: "{{ ip_newname[ansible_default_ipv4.address] }}"
      register: res
      when: ansible_default_ipv4.address in ip_newname.keys()
    - name: Reboot
        win_reboot:
      when: res is defined and res.reboot_required
```

Comment: I tried the first example you gave and it resulted in a failure. fatal: [10.x.x.1]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'ansible_default_ipv4.address == '10.x.x.1'' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (ansible_default_ipv4.address == '10.x.x.1') .

Comment: Ah sorry. I should have sanity checked that before posting. Ansible is a bit picky about raw string comparisons and requires the whole expression to be wrapped in double quotes, where for other comparisons it doesn't. Edited and tested my answer. Also, just to confirm, you are using the actual IP address in the code you run and not '10.x.x.1'?